# Looping through multiple text files and replacing characters

Tags: vba, loops, replace, vbscript

It's working now. Because of some file names consisting of Chinese characters or some empty files (created by my failed attempt to make this and not closing the file properly from vbs) it gave some error but I added the log so I can see the last file processed. I don't know how to make it show only the file that generated the error but it's ok like this too.

```
Const msoFileDialogOpen = 4

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set myLog = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\my.log", ForWriting, True)

strInitialPath = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("E:\Filme\")
objWord.ChangeFileOpenDirectory(strInitialPath)

Sub Modify(f)
  myLog.WriteLine f
  txt = f.OpenAsTextStream.ReadAll
  txt = Replace(txt, "ã", "a")
  txt = Replace(txt, "â", "a")
  f.OpenAsTextStream(2).Write txt
End Sub

Sub Recurse(fldr)
  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    Recurse sf
  Next
  For Each f In fldr.Files
    ext = LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(f.Name))
    If ext = "srt" Or ext = "sub" Or ext = "txt" Then Modify f
    REM WScript.Echo f
  Next
End Sub

With objWord.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
  .Title = "Select the folder to process"
  If .Show = -1 Then
    For Each item in .SelectedItems
      Recurse objFSO.GetFolder(item)
    Next
  Else
  End If
  myLog.Close
End With
```

Comment: What do you mean by "set to 4 for all the files"? [`MsoFileDialogType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432520%28v=office.12%29.aspx) 4 means you get to pick folders, not files.

Comment: Yes, I want to pick a folder and the script will open all srt,sub and txt files in it, do the replacement and save the file as it is. Sorry for not being clear. I've edited my post.

Comment: @FloRentin - `Set txt = f.OpenAsTextStream.ReadAll` PHOOEY!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to select a folder and then open all files with the extensions `.srt`, `.sub`, or `.txt` in that folder and all of its subfolders. For that you need a recursive procedure to traverse the folder subtree. It'd be a good idea to put the code for modifying the files in a second procedure. Makes for cleaner code.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Sub Modify(f)
  'code for modifying the files' content goes here
End Sub

Sub Recurse(fldr)
  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    Recurse sf
  Next
  For Each f In fldr.Files
    ext = LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(f.Name))
    If ext = "srt" Or ext = "sub" Or ext = "txt" Then Modify f
  Next
End Sub

...

With objWord.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
  ...
  For Each item in .SelectedItems
    Recurse objFSO.GetFolder(item)
  Loop
End With

...
```

There are some further optimizations you should apply to your code:

- It's a waste of resources to re-create `FileSystemObject` instances in a loop. Create a global instance once at the beginning of your script, and use that instance anywhere in the script.
- It's pointless to read a file line by line when you're reading the entire file into memory anyway. Just read the file with [`ReadAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t58aa4dd%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and run `Replace` on the whole text.
- Using `ReDim Preserve` in a loop is bound to perform poorly, because `ReDim` re-creates the variable, and `Preserve` copies all values from the old array instance to the new one.
- It's also pointless to obtain a file object, extract the full path, and then open that file by its path. Use the file object's [`OpenAsTextStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwfw5c59%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method instead.

Something like this should work:

```
Sub Modify(f)
  txt = f.OpenAsTextStream.ReadAll
  txt = Replace(txt, "ã", "a")
  txt = Replace(txt, "â", "a")
  ...
  f.OpenAsTextStream(2).Write txt
End Sub
```

Comment: @FloRentin My mistake. `.SelectedItems` is a collection of strings, but `Recurse()` expects a folder object. Use `objFSO.GetFolder()` to get the folder object for a given item. See updated answer.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - `Set txt = f.OpenAsTextStream.ReadAll` PFUI!

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers It still gives me an error. I hate that I don't understand this vbs... and I bother you with it...please excuse me.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Yes the error is somewhere there but I would like to know how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: @FloRentin - read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Comment: @FloRentin What Ekkehard is trying to tell you is: the `Set` keyword is only for assigning objects to variables. Since `ReadAll` returns a string, not an object, `Set` must not be used here.

Comment: THANKS TO EVERYONE especially to @AnsgarWiechers I could never do it without your help.